# What does resolve REALLY do in promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I thought I had a good understanding of Node and Promises but I got into this problem when I was trying to explain something for a friend of mine.

My question for you guys, is what is the expected output of this small script?

```js
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("inside promise")
    resolve("Lol!")

})

for (let i=0; i<1000000; i++) {}
// just want to be sure that the next line starts after the promise finishes execution

myPromise.then(() => console.log("then!"))

console.log("finished")
```

My expected output:

```
inside promise
finished
```

My thought was that if the promise finishes execution before the `myPromise.then(...` is read, then shouldn't the log never appear?

Actual output:

```
inside promise
finished
then!
```

If I emit the `resolve("Lol!")` though the expected output matches the actual output.

Can anybody explain me what is happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the empty `setTimeout` for?

Comment: OP seems to think it pauses the current execution. Which, of course isn't the case ...

Comment: Why, would `then!` ever not be logged in your scenario?

Comment: And why do you think the `then()` handler wouldn't be executed?

Comment: even if it did pause the execution it'd have no effect on the result.

Comment: It resolves the promise. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, the setTimeout is indeed useless, that previously was a empty for loop just to make sure the initial promise ended before the next line with the `then!` was processed. 

Basically what I was trying to understand is if `myPromise.then(() => console.log("then!"))` executes the promise again or not. If yes, shouldn't we see a `inside promise` again? And if not, shouldn't the then be ignored since the promise already fully executed

Comment: It doesn't. because... that's not what promises do. it's a promise, not a function.

Comment: "And if not, shouldn't the then be ignored since the promise already fully executed"

Comment: @AlexandreRamalho no, `then()` means "do this after the promise resolves". It doesn't matter *when* you call the `.then()` - it always means the same thing. Oherwise it will not be terribly useful if it might some times not fire and thus change what your code does. Especially if you have little control over when code is executed. You don't want `p.then(foo)` to some times fire some times not based on how the async tasks are scheduled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS promise gives you the option to run code asynchronously. So you signal the JS engine that you would like to preform an action once another action is finished. Since actions can be successful or not promises can be resolved (`resolve`) or rejected (`reject`). For handling success you use `then` for handling fail you use `catch`, optional after both you can use `finally`.

So when you declare a promise the JS engine knows it is not something you need now, rather later. **It will start the execution but will relate to its result later on. After starting the promise action it will runs through the rest of the synchronous commands**, in you case all except the `then`. Once dohe ne it will check if it has promises that already had been resolved, if yes it will execute the relevant `than`.

**The `resolve()` puts the `then` of the promise to the callback queue. Later on when the call-stack will be empty the engine will handle that. Same would go for `reject()` but with `catch`.**

If you would like to keep a cleaner syntax I recommend to check async-await.

*also note that your `setTimeout` is not giving you anything. If you put `console.log` in it, it will also be shown only after the 'finish'.

Comment: Thank you for that. That callback queue explains it. 
I only have one question:
You said that JS knows that I don't need the promise now, so it will execute after all the synchronous commands. But doesn't that mean that the order of outputs seen should be `finished > inside promise > then!`? since the console.log is also synchronous?

Comment: @AlexandreRamalho, thanks for reading carefully!
I edited the part about it. Since the code you placed inside the promise is synchronous it will run right when the promise is created.
In the traditional example you will have there asynchronous code like `setTimeout` and then it will run later.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your example annotated:

```js
console.log('Before myPromise is created');

const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // This is executed immediately when a new
    // Promise is created, so it will appear
    // BEFORE 'After myPromise is created'.
    console.log("Inside promise")
   
    // This passes the value "Lol!" to
    // the 'then' function. By itself it
    // does not console log anything.
    resolve("Lol!")
})

console.log('After myPromise is created');

// This does nothing, code immediately
// carries on executing. After >=100ms a function
// doing nothing is called.
setTimeout(() => {}, 100)

// The 'then' is passed the argument of
// `resolve()` (in this case "Lol!")
myPromise.then(resolveArg => console.log(resolveArg))

// Second to last console log because
// all .then() handlers are called asynchronously
// once the main thread is idle (as the Promises/A+
// spec says, when the JS engine returns back to 
// "platform code"). Therefore "Lol!" will be the 
// last thing logged.
console.log("Finished")
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Promise()` handles the operation it has to "wait for", then returns the result to the `then ()` command - this is an asynchronous operation. Consider the following example:

```js
const myPromise = (val1, val2) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      val1 > val2 
        ? setTimeout(() => resolve("LOL !!!"), 1500)
        : reject("\"val2\" is greater than \"val1\"");
   });    
}

// Then you call:
myPromise(5, 1).then(

   // Processing results:
   function (result) {
      console.log("This is result: ", result);
   },
   
   // Error handling from "reject()"
   function(error) {
      console.log("This is an error: ", error);
   }
)

// error case:
myPromise(1, 5).then(

   // Processing results:
   function (result) {
      console.log("This is result: ", result);
   },
   
   // Error handling from "reject()"
   // the result in console.log will be first than in the case of resolve()
   function(error) {
      console.log("This is an error: ", error);
   }
)

// Error handling with 'catch' block
myPromise(1,5)
   .then((result) => console.log(result))
   .catch((err) => console.log("This is error: ", err, "# with catch-block"))
```